# Export certificate chain from .cer certificate

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I have .cer certificate. When I'm opening it, it shows me certificate chain.

[image: Click to show image]

Using this code, I read the certificate to x509certificate file.

```
File certificateFile = new File("C:\\Users\\grish\\Desktop\\certificateForValidation.cer");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(certificateFile);

        X509Certificate certificate = new X509CertImpl(inputStream);
```

I want to get certificate chain from that file ! (end-entity, CA, Root)
How can I do that programmatically in java.

With C#, this is much more easy

```
X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();
ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
ch.Build (certificate);
```

And then I can get all certificates from ch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether CA and ROOT also are contained in that .cer file (which in your code example has a .p7b extension... wtf?); if they are, @sebmal's answer should show the way; if they are not... Have you tried using the Java [CertPathBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#CertPathBuilder) class yet?

Comment: Oh no, God. That must be .cer file, sorry ! FROM p7b I can read all certificates

Comment: Certpathbuilder need Issuer certificate, which doesn't exist in .cer file

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you are using the `java.security.cert` package; see [JDK 17 API doc for java.security.cert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/package-summary.html).

Avoid using `javax.security.cert`. The package is marked as deprecated an will be removed in future releases; see [JDK 17 API doc for javax.security.cert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/security/cert/package-summary.html).

The following code will return a collection of `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` objects. In the case of your example with the certificate of medium.com the list will contain three items; one for every certificate in the chain.

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\grish\\Desktop\\Coding Space\\Certificates\\certificateForValidation.p7b")) {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        List<X509Certificate> certs = (List<X509Certificate>) cf.generateCertificates(inStream);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tested it with a PEM formated chain but it should work with PCKS#7 (.p7b file extension) as well; see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificates(java.io.InputStream)) of the `generateCertificates(InputStream inStream)` method.

Find more information about x.509 encoding and conversion [here](https://www.ssl.com/guide/pem-der-crt-and-cer-x-509-encodings-and-conversions/)